# How to play the music in the Bluetooth speaker programmatically?

Tags: bluetooth, xamarin.android

I want to play the audio of my app to Bluetooth enabled speaker in Xamarin.

I tried with this code. It is not working. It throws an error like invalid cast exception for `MBluetoothAdapter.GetProfileProxy`. Can anyone please suggest how to do it in **Xamarin.Android**?

```
private IBluetoothProfileServiceListener _bluetoothProfileServiceListener;

public BluetoothAdapter MBluetoothAdapter;
```

In `onCreate`:

```
MBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.DefaultAdapter;
_bluetoothProfileServiceListener = new ServiceListener();
MBluetoothAdapter.GetProfileProxy(BaseContext, 
_bluetoothProfileServiceListener, ProfileType.A2dp);

private class ServiceListener : IBluetoothProfileServiceListener
    {
        public void Dispose()
        {
        }

        public IntPtr Handle { get; }
public void OnServiceConnected(ProfileType profile,IBluetoothProfile proxy)
        {
            if (profile == ProfileType.A2dp)
            {
                //service connected   
            }
        }

        public void OnServiceDisconnected(ProfileType profile)
        {
        }
    }
```